# warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]

Tags: c

How can I solve this warning?

CODE:

```
#define tofile(L,i) (tofileh(L,i)->f)
static FileHandle *tofileh (lua_State *L, int findex) {
  FileHandle *fh = topfile(L, findex);
  if (fh->f == NULL)
    luaL_error(L, "attempt to use a closed file");
  return fh;
}
```

I have no idea about this warning.
points to this line;

```
(tofileh(L,i)->f)
```

Comment: What exactly is producing the warning? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: The compiler is complaining about your use of the macro, not the function definition. How are you using it?

Comment: Original metin2 source code. /liblua/src/lib/liolib.c @user17732522

Comment: I need to solve this too. can you help me?

Comment: @user17732522: That is bad advice; this is a good warning from the compiler, and the code causing it should be inspected and improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `(tofileh(L,i)->f)`, after the function returns a value, `->f` evaluates the member `f`. This evaluation has no effect. It is not used in an assignment or a print operation or in anything else where it would do anything.

Evaluating an expression with no effect is often a sign of a mistake in source code, so the compiler warns you. To fix it, change the code to do something useful. The question does not provide sufficient context to determine why this source code is present, so advice cannot be given on what should be done instead.